# Changing value of a netcdf file for a variable

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a large netcdf file which is three dimensional. I want to replace for the variable `LU_INDEX` in the netcdf file all the values 10 with 2.

I wrote this python script to do so but it does not seem to work.

```
filelocation = 'D:/dataset.nc'

ncdataset = nc.Dataset(filelocation,'r')
lat           = ncdataset.variables['XLAT_M'][0,:,:]
lon           = ncdataset.variables['XLONG_M'][0,:,:]
lu_index     = ncdataset.variables['LU_INDEX'][0,:,:]
lu_index_new = lu_index
ncdataset.close()

nlat,nlon=lat.shape

for ilat in range(nlat):
    for ilon in range(lon):
        if lu_index == 10:
          lu_index_new[ilat,ilon] = 2

newfilename = 'D:/dataset.new.nc'
copyfile(ncdataset,newfilename)


newfile     = nc.Dataset(newfilename,'r+')
newfile.variables['LU_INDEX'][0,:,:]   = lu_index_new
newfile.close()
```

I get the error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I am not a very experienced with python, so if there is a more easier way to do this you are very welcome to comment.

Answer (score 9):

You might try [NCO](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2)

```
ncap2 -s 'where(LU_INDEX == 10) LU_INDEX=2' in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out as follow:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np

pathname = 'D:'
filename = '%s/dataset.nc'%pathname
ncfile = nc.Dataset(filename,'r+')
lu_index = ncfile.variables['LU_INDEX'][:]
I = np.where(lu_index == 10)
lu_index[I] = 2
ncfile.variables['LU_INDEX'][:] = lu_index
filename.close()

print 'conversion complete'
```

Comment: The concision difference between the NCO and Python solutions is striking.

Comment: NCO is probably 1000x faster too. Pro tip: always leverage NCO where possible.

Comment: not just faster but also memory efficient. It's an awesome set of programs! Thanks Charlie

Answer (score 2):

using np.array might not work for a very large dataset with the following error

"ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size."

CDO can be a nice tool other than NCO and for me, it is much faster.

```
cdo setvals,10,2 in.nc out.nc
```

It is particularly fast when you have to replace values in more than one variables in the same nc file (e.g. replace missing values representation).
One can use `setrtoc` in place of `setval` for specifying a range.